# how Oracle database to connect with google sheets

Tags: oracle, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want Oracle  database to connect with google sheets and export data into spreadsheet. Is there any way from oracle to authentication with google and export data to Google spreadsheet

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the Sheets REST API. Note that your use case is strange, as databases generally store and query data, while external applications call database for their input.

Comment: Thanks tehhowch, Please could you share how to use REST API and share if any examples

Comment: there are plenty of examples on the REST API reference pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In google scripts the following should work:

```
Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipaddress:1521:SID","username","password");
```

You may use `ipaddress` or `hostname` But your `ipaddress` or `hostname` has to be public or you need to whitelist the google script ips[1]

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#setup_for_other_databases

Comment: Thanks Riyafa.. But I need vice-versa, To connect from Oracle database to Google sheet and export data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Skyvia for connecting Google Sheets and Oracle data without coding. If you need to simply copy Google Sheets data to Oracle without mapping configuration, you can use Skyvia replication:

https://skyvia.com/data-integration/integrate-google-sheets-oracle. If you want to work directly from the Google Sheets interface, you can use Skyvia Query Google Sheets:

https://skyvia.com/google-sheets-addon/oracle. I prefer the second option.